# Chart.js bar chart is not rendering after updating data after ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax, charts

in my current project, a bar chart is to be updated dynamically, i.e. when a button is used to go forward or back a month, the data for that month is to be displayed.
First I load an empty chart and then load the data into the chart so that it can be displayed.

I use Chart.js and my Pie Charts, which I use, can be updated without further ado, but when I try to do this with this Bar Chart, the labels and data are read out and also displayed, but not rendered. If i load the page in the logs i got 60 time the error `GET "http:://localhost/fitnesslaeufer-redesign/diary/undefined`, but only with this code. If i add this all in one function everything is working fine.

What am i doing wrong?

Expacted Look / Output:
[image: Expected Output]

Current status:
[image: Current Status]

Data and Labels will be loaded / updated but not rendered:
[image: Data and Labels will be loaded / updated]

Error Messages:
[image: Error Messages]

Example Output from the Ajax call:

```
[{"training_date":"01.09.2021","distance":0},{"training_date":"02.09.2021","distance":0},{"training_date":"03.09.2021","distance":0},{"training_date":"04.09.2021","distance":0},{"training_date":"05.09.2021","distance":0},{"training_date":"06.09.2021","distance":0},{"training_date":"07.09.2021","distance":0},{"training_date":"08.09.2021","distance":0},{"training_date":"09.09.2021","distance":0},{"training_date":"10.09.2021","distance":0},{"training_date":"11.09.2021","distance":0},{"training_date":"12.09.2021","distance":0},{"training_date":"13.09.2021","distance":0},{"training_date":"14.09.2021","distance":0},{"training_date":"15.09.2021","distance":0},{"training_date":"16.09.2021","distance":0},{"training_date":"17.09.2021","distance":0},{"training_date":"18.09.2021","distance":0},{"training_date":"19.09.2021","distance":0},{"training_date":"20.09.2021","distance":0},{"training_date":"21.09.2021","distance":0},{"training_date":"22.09.2021","distance":0},{"training_date":"23.09.2021","distance":0},{"training_date":"24.09.2021","distance":0},{"training_date":"25.09.2021","distance":0},{"training_date":"26.09.2021","distance":0},{"training_date":"27.09.2021","distance":0},{"training_date":"28.09.2021","distance":0},{"training_date":"29.09.2021","distance":0},{"training_date":"30.09.2021","distance":0}]
```

```js
userDiaryMonthTrainingDistanceStatsChart();
var userDiaryMonthTrainingDistanceStats = userDiaryMonthTrainingDistanceStatsChart();
userDiaryMonthTrainingDistanceStatsData(user_id, filtermonth, filteryear, userDiaryMonthTrainingDistanceStats);

function userDiaryMonthTrainingDistanceStatsChart() {

    var options = {
        legend: {
            display: false,
            position: 'top',

            labels: {
                fontSize: 16,
                boxWidth: 40,
            }
        },
        plugins: {
            labels: {
                render: 'value',
                fontSize: 14,
                fontStyle: 'bold'
            }
        },
        layout: {
            padding: {
                left: 0,
                right: 0,
                top: 30,
                bottom: 0
            }
        }
    };

    var ctx = $("#monthly_training_distance_stats");

    var userDiaryMonthTrainingDistanceStats = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            datasets: [{
                backgroundColor: '#00a3ff',
                borderColor: '#00a3ff',
                hoverBackgroundColor: '#CCCCCC',
                hoverBorderColor: '#666666',
            }]
        },
        options: options
    });

    return userDiaryMonthTrainingDistanceStats
}

function userDiaryMonthTrainingDistanceStatsData(user_id, month, year, chart) {

    $.ajax({
        url: "../diary/includes/training/diary-training-monthly-training-distance-stats.php?user_id=" + user_id  + "&month=" + month + "&year=" + year,
        type: "GET",
        success: function(monthly_training_distance_stats) {

            var distance = [];
            var training_date = [];

            for(var i in monthly_training_distance_stats) {
                distance.push(monthly_training_distance_stats[i].distance),
                training_date.push(monthly_training_distance_stats[i].training_date)
            }

            var userMonthlyTrainingDistanceStatsDataLabels = [training_date];
            var userMonthlyTrainingDistanceStatsData = [distance];

            chart.data.labels[0] = [training_date];
            chart.data.datasets[0].labels = [training_date];
            chart.data.datasets[0].data = [distance];
            chart.update();
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of testing and researching, I found the solution.
In my code I have to update the chart data in the for loop of the function (userDiaryMonthTrainingDistanceStatsData()).

```js
function userDiaryMonthTrainingDistanceStatsData(user_id, month, year, chart) {

    $.ajax({
        url: "../diary/includes/training/diary-training-monthly-training-distance-stats.php?user_id=" + user_id  + "&month=" + month + "&year=" + year,
        type: "GET",
        success: function(monthly_training_distance_stats) {

            var distance = [];
            var training_date = [];

            for(var i in monthly_training_distance_stats) {
                distance.push(monthly_training_distance_stats[i].distance),
                training_date.push(monthly_training_distance_stats[i].training_date)

                chart.data.labels = training_date;
                chart.data.datasets.labels = training_date;
                chart.data.datasets[0].data = distance;
                chart.update();
            }
        }
    })
}
```